Question on how to multiply timeframe logic
I have a strategy script that uses higher timeframes with the current timeframe on the chart. After some backtesting & research, I've discovered a mathetimatical pattern with which upper timeframes work with the current timeframes on the chart.
This is my discovery:
Example- lets say I put the chart on a 1hr timeframe. I've noticed that if I multiply 60(1hr for current chart) by 120 (60*120) the answer is 7200(minutes) which also equates to 5D. I then use that timeframe (5D) as my primary timeframe.
for the second timeframe to use, using the same chart (1hr timeframe). I've noticed that if I multiply 60(1hr for current chart) by 20 (60*20) the answer is 1200(minutes) which also equates to 20H. I then use that timeframe (20H) as my secondary timeframe.
Using 120 & 20 to multiply the current chart in minutes with those numbers have made me found that the backtested settings are always profitable.
So here is my question:
Is there a way to add that equation within pinescript? I would like my strategy script to automatically calculate which timeframes to use using that equation and also analyzing which current timeframe the chart is on. An example would be nice and I can figure out the rest.
(multiplied in minutes)


You can get the current timeframe in seconds with timeframe.in_seconds().
Then you can do your calculation and use the result in request.security(). However, the timeframe argument of request.security() expects a string in a specific format. So, you cannot just pass 7200 as a string. You need to convert this to the expected format - 5D, in this example.

Timeframe strings follow these rules:

They are composed of the multiplier and the timeframe unit, e.g., “1S”, “30” (30 minutes), “1D” (one day), “3M” (three months).

The unit is represented by a single letter, with no letter used for minutes: “S” for seconds, “D” for days, “W” for weeks and “M” for
months.

When no multiplier is used, 1 is assumed: “S” is equivalent to “1S”, “D” to “1D, etc. If only “1” is used, it is interpreted as
“1min”, since no unit letter identifier is used for minutes.

There is no “hour” unit; “1H” is not valid. The correct format for one hour is “60” (remember no unit letter is specified for minutes).


The valid multipliers vary for each timeframe unit:

For seconds, only the discrete 1, 5, 10, 15 and 30 multipliers are valid.
For minutes, 1 to 1440.
For days, 1 to 365.
For weeks, 1 to 52.
For months, 1 to 12.


I have written a function that does this conversion for you.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

MONTH_IN_MIN = 43800
WEEK_IN_MIN = 10080
DAY_IN_MIN = 1440


f_convert_tf_to_string(p_tf_in_min) =>
    string ret_val = ""

    if (p_tf_in_min >= MONTH_IN_MIN)                                    // Month
        ret_val := str.tostring(int(p_tf_in_min / MONTH_IN_MIN)) + "M"
    else if (p_tf_in_min >= WEEK_IN_MIN)                                // Week
        ret_val := str.tostring(int(p_tf_in_min / WEEK_IN_MIN)) + "W"
    else if (p_tf_in_min >= DAY_IN_MIN)                                 // Day
        ret_val := str.tostring(int(p_tf_in_min / DAY_IN_MIN)) + "D"
    else if (p_tf_in_min >= 1)                                          // Minutes and hours
        ret_val := str.tostring(p_tf_in_min)
    // else -> Seconds not handled in this function


multiplier = 120
tf_in_min = timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period) / 60

htf = f_convert_tf_to_string(tf_in_min * multiplier)

if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Timeframe: " + htf, textcolor=color.white)

close_htf = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, htf, close)  // 5D close price when used on 1h timeframe

plot(close_htf, "HTF - Close", color.white, 2)

Edit:
Or you can simply use the built-in function timeframe.from_seconds
htf = timeframe.from_seconds(timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period) * multiplier)



Thanks! the calculation seems to work well with my script. However, I keep getting this error on the strategy tester when I put the timeframe on higher intervals:
"Invalid value of the 'resolution' argument ('13M') in the 'security' function."
any thoughts?

Because the max value is 12M. See the user manual.

There's also a built-in timeframe.from_seconds() function that converts a number of seconds into a valid timeframe while handling outliers (like anything above 12M): https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_timeframe.from_seconds

@beeholder Oh, yes. How did I miss that :) Gonna update my answer.
